# Java http read timeout issue

Tags: java, http, networking

I am trying to get some data from remote server. To achieve this I use `HttpURLConnection`. The problem is that sometimes the server after connection is established just hangs or what, doesn't close connection, and I hang there. Also that hanged thread acquired the lock, so all all other threads are just sucking :D
Code:

```
try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), Charset.forName(CharEncoding.UTF_8)));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
```

Last line is where we are hanging. I found method `setConnectTimeout(timeout)`, but seems this is not the case because it is timeout before connection is established. What is common way to solve such situations?

Comment: timeout before the connection established? then you wouldn't come all the way down to the while loop, or am I misunderstanding something??

Comment: Sorry, I has wrote not clear here.I meant found such method in class HttpURLConnection ;) No time outs were in my code ..

Comment: no worries I'm glad if I could help solve out the problem whatever it was :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming you meant timeout after the connection is established (likely during the read), how about something like this

```
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(c_timeout);
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(r_timeout);
stream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't find this method. Seems read timeout will solve this issue. Thanks! Will try tommorow.